# jquery hide/show multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

EDIT: My post differs from duplicate because my link ids are generated at pageload with PHP so I can't call a specific number like the duplicate topic shows. I'd need to grab variables sent along the link, which is the part I'm struggling with I think

---

I want to add a feature on my messageboard that hides posts of a low user rating, with a link saying "low rated post, click to show". When the person clicks that link, it would hide the current div and make the post div visible in its place.

My jquery is scratchy at best so could someone just nudge me in the correct direction as to which bits are wrong? So the links would be something like;

```
<div id=hiddenpost_500><a href="#" data-id="post_?" id="show"></div>
<div id=hiddenpost_501><a href="#" data-id="post_?" id="show"></div>
<div id=hiddenpost_502><a href="#" data-id="post_?" id="show"></div>
```

Then the jquery on pageload (not sure how some of it is phrased);

```
$('show').click(function() {
  var post_id = $(this).data('id');
  $("#post_" + post_id).show();
  $("#hiddenpost_" + post_id).hide();
  return false;
  });
```

Then, the post divs?

```
<div id=post_500>blah blah</div>
<div id=post_501>blah blah</div>
<div id=post_502>blah blah</div>
```

How close am I?

Comment: I'd suggest setting the rating as a `data-*` attribute rather than `id`. and what is a *low rating* out of those values..?

Comment: My post ids are generated with PHP so I can't call a specific number like the duplicate topic shows. I'd need to grab variables sent along the link.